# How to retrieve tags from an Instagram photo?

Tags: tumblr, if-this-then-that, instagram, instagram-tags, tumblr-tags

I use IFTTT to put my liked Instagram photos into my Tumblr feed using [this recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/88864). I would like to use the tags from the Instagram photo as tags for the Tumblr post, but the hashtags from the photo captions are not among the elements that can be used as tags in a Tumblr post in IFTTT.

From my limited knowledge of the IG API it seems like you can retrieve photos *by* tags or *by* which photos a given user (myself in this case) has liked, but I cannot figure out how/if I can retrieve the tags from a given photo (the hashtags from the photo caption) to be used as tags in Tumblr.

Is there a way to get the tags from an Instagram photo's caption separate from the caption itself?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't look possible with IFTTT right now. Even if you could get a feed of your liked photos, the "Feed" channel in IFTTT doesn't have a "tags" ingredient, either.